# Missing permissions "Forbidden" error catching

Tags: discord.py, pycord

So I searched on GitHub, reddit & other questions in Stack Overflow but I nowhere found a way how to catch Forbidden - missing permissions error:

```
discord.commands.errors.ApplicationCommandInvokeError: Application Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

Basically I've already solved this problem, just use `commands.discord.Forbidden` error in `async def on_command_error(ctx, error)`, but... could someone show me the clearest way, like `Forbidden({"error":"text"})` instead of common method. Also I use `commands.slash_command`, maybe it has a difference.

I don't know `Forbidden` syntax. Also I need the same `NotFound` answer if I need channel error instead of Member Thanks so much who helps me!

Comment: In this case it was a `discord.commands.errors.ApplicationCommandInvokeError`

Comment: I know, but I can catch it with Forbidden, tested.

Comment: Then I don't get what your questions is

Comment: just how to set discord.Forbidden & NotFound error handler with arguments (Missing Permissions - who missed, like member, bot? author or other)

Just in case: discord.errors.Forbidden(response=`idk`, message="Missing permissions"), like that